# importing data into r from txt file with missing values

Tags: r, import, missing-data, numeric-input

I am having trouble importing data correctly into r from a txt file with missing values. When I import, the column of numeric values with the missing value (have tried it both as `"."` and `"Na"`) is read as a factor variable. The import code I use is:

```
dat2 <- read.table(file.choose(), header = T)
```

Looking at the structure of the data, I see for the column of interest:

```
adultreg    : Factor w/ 19 levels "1.85","101.75",..: 11 15 15 1 13 6 17 9 16 3
```

After converting the factor to the numeric variable `(dat2$adultreg<-as.numeric(dat2$adultreg)`, I ask r to output the data just so I can see what it is, it is not at all the data from the text file anymore.

Comment: You should use `read.table(...,`stringsAsFactors =FALSE`).

Answer (score 1):

Factors in R are tricky - they are actually stored as integers, where each integer is decoded based on what are called `levels`.

The most intuitive method for conversion is `as.numeric(as.character(dat2$adultreg))`

The fastest way (I believe) is `levels(dat2$adultreg)[dat2$adultreg]`

Comment: thanks. that does help. but now when i try to create a linear model with the variables containing missing values i get an error saying there are missing values in the objects. how should i mark these in my original data so that this doesn't happen? or is it in the import commands that i deal with this appropriately?

Comment: @user2880353 this comment is not related to the original question. AVOID asking many questions in the same OP. That's said , You need only to remove your missings values.